# How to code collection find with regex and complex criteria using Java MongoDB driver?

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I have the following query in MongoDB:

```
db.cache.find({objectKey: { $regex: 'Bos*'}, cacheVersionString:'08/03/15_11:05:09'},
{ _id:0, objectData:0, lastModified :0, productCode:0})
```

Also, I would like to calculate number of records, that is possible in Mongo shell by using count

```
db.cache.find({objectKey: { $regex: 'Bos*'}, cacheVersionString:'08/03/15_11:05:09'},
{ _id:0, objectData:0, lastModified :0, productCode:0}).count()
```

How to write the analogous queries in Java using Java MongoDB driver, version 3?

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/

Comment: I could not find how to use regex in Java find, in this document either

Comment: Okay, I haven't dug very deep into that doc.  But from using the C# driver, there is something left to be desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing queries is really just creating BSON document representation, which is basically just the same interface as standard HashMap or List interfaces as appropriate:

```
    Document query = new Document("objectKey",new Document( "$regex","Bos"))
        .append("cacheVersionString","08/03/15_11:05:09");

    Document projection = new Document("_id",0)
        .append("objectData",0)
        .append("lastModified",0)
        .append("productCode",0);

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).projection(projection).iterator();
```

Where that is basically identical to how you are structuring queries in the MongoDB shell.

Alternately you can use builder interfaces if that seems more logical to you:

```
    QueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilder.start();

    builder.and("objectKey").regex(Pattern.compile("box"));
    builder.and("cache_version_string").is("08/03/15_11:05:09");

    BasicDBObject query = (BasicDBObject)builder.get();

    Bson projection = Projections.exclude(
            "_id",
            "obectdata",
            "lasModified",
            "productCode"
    );

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).projection(projection).iterator();

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = cursor.next();
        System.out.println(doc.toJson());
    }
```

Both forms essentially contruct the BSON for both the "query" and "projection" components and issue them as arguments to the `.find()` method. There are also class type definitions if that suits you as well.

Comment: thank you.  I also added the question about count, do you have any idea?