# How to get count after using find with Java MongoDB driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I was answered about constructing a MongoDb query

[How to code collection find with regex and complex criteria using Java MongoDB driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843632/how-to-code-collection-find-with-regex-and-complex-criteria-using-java-mongodb-d)

Still the question about a count was unanswered:
So for this query how to write an analogous Java code returning count:

```
db.cache.find({objectKey: { $regex: 'Bos*'}, cacheVersionString:'08/03/15_11:05:09'}).count()
```

Comment: Do you use Spring Data maybe?

Comment: Not for this collection

Comment: And what is generally your approach to use Java and Mongo?

Comment: either this Driver or SpringData

Answer (score 0):

With `MongoTemplate`, it would be something like this:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("objectKey").regex("Bos*"));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("cacheVersionString").is("08/03/15_11:05:09"));
long count = mongoTemplate.count(query, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: The cache collection is not mapped to any class

Comment: Just map it. It's much easier then to process raw results returned by driver.

Comment: What if the mapping is not accurate?